# Why does .NET Core authentication fail after setting a cookie path?

Tags: c#, .net-core

When I am setting a cookie path the following way, in the startup.cs

```
.AddCookie(opts =>
            {

                opts.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                opts.LoginPath = "/Account/SignIn";
                opts.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                opts.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                opts.SessionStore = authSessionStore;
                opts.Cookie.Path = "/api";
            });
```

Authentication fails. To authenticate I am using Azure/Microsoft login, if does make sense. It just keeps refreshing the browser when trying to log in, I mean when I press the login button to go to the Microsoft login page, no error in the console whatsoever. Inside the output I can see the following lines:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information:
> Authorization failed for user: (null).
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing
> ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().

Any ideas on why this happens, and how I could fix it by keeping the path specified?

It works fine when the path is removed. I'm using .NET Core 2.0

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .Net Core 2.1.x onwards then you need to add IsEssential = true

```
.AddCookie(opts =>
        {

            opts.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            opts.LoginPath = "/Account/SignIn";
            opts.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            opts.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            opts.SessionStore = authSessionStore;
            opts.Cookie.Path = "/api";
            opts.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is 2.0